# Android app crashes on phone, but not tablet

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with the phone version of the application crashing on startup.  The splash screen launches fine, but the app crashes after opening the main activity.  I've also changed the main activity which has eliminated the problem, so it seems that the problem must be coming from said activity.  Here's my log.  If it would help for me to post the java or xml code for the crashing activity, I can as well.  I have separate layout files for the phone and tablet dimensions, but they are nearly identical.  I'm not too familiar working with the log entries, so any help is appreciated.

```
02-23 13:08:03.368: D/FragmentAdapter(13436): onCreate
02-23 13:08:03.368: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): initMyAp
02-23 13:08:03.368: I/File(13436): Yes, manifest version is the same as the stored version
02-23 13:08:03.378: I/File(13436): reading Ap settings header; version=23
02-23 13:08:03.378: I/File(13436): strSettings_Favorite5=Favorite5
02-23 13:08:03.378: I/File(13436): Settings Read Succesfully
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/de.bmc.p/files/file_LastBTaddr: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:780)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:179)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at de.bmc.p.FragmentAdapter.initMyAp(FragmentAdapter.java:660)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at de.bmc.p.FragmentAdapter.onCreate(FragmentAdapter.java:385)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-23 13:08:03.378: W/System.err(13436):    ... 19 more
02-23 13:08:03.378: I/File(13436): reading last BMC addr: null
02-23 13:08:05.441: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): getBluetoothGoing
02-23 13:08:05.451: W/DavesBTHandler(13436): initBluetooth - successful
02-23 13:08:05.451: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): getBluetoothGoing() - poup window
02-23 13:08:05.481: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): creating FragmentAdapterTask Handlers
02-23 13:08:05.481: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): mFragStatusTask.run() issue, eActiveFragmentNow=Splash
02-23 13:08:05.491: I/FragmentAdapter(13436): onResume
02-23 13:08:05.491: I/File(13436): writing new settings file: 23
02-23 13:08:05.521: W/DavesBTHandler(13436): resumeBThandler() called
02-23 13:08:05.521: D/DavesBTHandler(13436): start
02-23 13:08:05.641: D/FragmentAdapter(13436): FragmentKickoff=0
02-23 13:08:05.641: D/FragmentAdapter(13436): FragmentKickoff=1
02-23 13:08:05.651: I/Accessories(13436): onCreate
02-23 13:08:05.761: I/Accessories(13436): onCreateView
02-23 13:08:05.791: I/Accessories(13436): onActivityCreated
02-23 13:08:05.791: I/Massage(13436): onCreate
02-23 13:08:05.791: I/Massage(13436): onCreateView
02-23 13:08:05.791: W/ResourceType(13436): Failure getting entry for 0x7f03000b (t=2 e=11) in package 0 (error -75)
02-23 13:08:05.791: D/AndroidRuntime(13436): Shutting down VM
02-23 13:08:05.801: W/dalvikvm(13436): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415c1ba8)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436): Process: de.bmc.p, PID: 13436
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03000b
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at de.bmc.p.MassageFragment.onCreateView(MassageFragment.java:116)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 13:08:05.801: E/AndroidRuntime(13436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 13:08:07.933: I/Process(13436): Sending signal. PID: 13436 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MassageFragment.onCreateView()` you inflate a view that references resource id `0x7f03000b` that is not found.

Check your `R.java` to learn what resource `0x7f03000b` points to and check that it's really there in the phone resources variant.

In the log there's another `ENOENT` file not found exception a couple of seconds earlier, too, but that does not seem to cause your crash.